# Truncate Table from function doesn't work for an specific postgresql table

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm migrating data from a database in Oracle to a Database in Postgresql.
During the testing process I have to delete all the data from the PostgreSQL tables.
For this I made a function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mod_migracion.fn_clear_database() 
RETURNS void AS
$$
declare 
var1 text;
BEGIN 

SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || string_agg(format('%I.%I', schemaname, tablename), ', ') ||
 ' CASCADE' into var1 FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname like 'mod%' ;
 raise notice '%',var1;
  execute var1;
 END
 $$ 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function works fine and supposedly erases all data.
When starting the migration everything works fine, but in a specific table it throws me an error of duplicate key violates unique constraint.
The funny thing is that there is nothing duplicate. It seems that the data in that table is never deleted when in fact it is truncated.
Can anybody help me.
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Can you verify that the table is not empty afterwards? Add a `RAISE NOTICE` in your function that displays the SQL statement and see if the table is in the list.

Comment: yes, after executing the function the table is empty. The funny thing is that if I perform the truncate table by table without using the function it does not give the error.

Comment: Ok, and what does the SQL statement your function executes look like? Does it contain the table in question?

Comment: I already solved the problem. The function works correctly. The problem was an ETL with an incorrect step. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem. The function works correctly. The problem was an ETL with an incorrect step. Thank you.!